# Infinite Login Loop in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, login, login-screen, disk, disk-usage

I'm facing an infinite login loop in ubuntu 20.04.
I'm guessing that it's because of the error "No space left on device" but I'm not sure. I don't understand why I'm having a space issue though and how to solve it.

Comment: If you have no space in $HOME (your user directory), GUI work files cannot be created and a GUI login will fail without message & you'll be logged out again (ie. login loop).  You can however login via text terminal to correct situation (if this is a desktop login, recommended minimum space is 25GB of disk space, but many of us need more than that minimum)

Comment: Yes, my home directory is full. What can I do to rectify this? Also, why is it that this directory got full so quickly?

Comment: As to how it filled so quickly you'll need to access people who use it, plus whoever installed it as to what size disk space was allocated. Did you go larger than the 25GB recommended minimum? or just that? or use smaller?  Every program you add takes space out of / (esp. containerized apps) so you need to allocate space according to what apps you need (many blogs suggest small space because they don't add apps). To rectify it you need to erase files, or increase partition size but you've given no details as to space allocated or your disks.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1pljOCSln5zwNsQO5gcv5Kx1qNM7KH-Uh

Comment: Please check this link

Comment: Please notice that tmpfs occupies 786M space. I'm not sure but is it way too much than required? Please guide me on how to fix this.

Comment: You have loads of space in /home (the $HOME I mentioned in my first comment is /home/$USER/ or your user directory which will be on the sda7 partition which has plenty of space)  Your issue maybe related to something else that didn't complete because of lack of space. I'd recommend find something you can delete on /

Comment: I delete snap/snapshots folder and I could login. What can I do to prevent this error of "no space left" again? I have been constantly getting notified about this.